# "Moment of inertia" of uniform distribution on the hypersphere

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

I would like to compute the following moment for the uniform distribution defined on the hypersphere (sometimes referred to as the moment of inertia):

> $\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}} \theta \theta^\top \sigma(\mathrm{d}\theta),$

where $\mathbb{S}^{d-1} = \{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d ; \|\theta\|=1\}$ is the d-dimensional hypersphere and $\sigma(\mathrm{d} \theta)$ denotes the *uniform distribution* on $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$.

Numerically, I have confirmed that the answer is $\frac1{d}I$, where $I$ is the $d\times d$ identity matrix, but I failed to prove it formally.

I wanted to use the fact that if $x \sim N(0,I)$ then $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ is uniformly distributed on the sphere, but I couldn't go very far.  I would be very happy if someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look at the *off-diagonal* entries of your matrix. Writing $\theta = (\theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots, \theta_d)$ you have the integral is

$$  \int_{\mathbb{S}^d} \theta_i \theta_j \sigma(\mathrm{d}\theta) $$

where $i \neq j$. Notice that $\theta_i$ is an "odd" function under reflection of the $i$th coordinate, and similarly $\theta_j$. This tells you that the above integral vanishes (as the sphere is reflectionally symmetric).

Next look at the *diagonal* entries. By symmetry each of the diagonal entries should be the same. If you look at the *trace* of this matrix, you have the integral

$$ \int_{\mathbb{S}^d} \|\theta\|^2 \sigma(\mathrm{d}\theta) $$

so using that $\|\theta\|^2 = 1$ on the sphere you have that this total integral evaluates to $1$.

Given that each of the entries are the same, each entry along the diagonal must have magnitude $1/d$ in return.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, I'm a little bit confused about the off-diagonal part: could you write it more explicitly?

Comment: @thmusic: maybe this will help: you can do a rotation of the sphere $\theta_1 \to \theta_2$ and $\theta_2 \to - \theta_1$. Your set-up is symmetric so the moment of inertia shouldn't change. But the explicit integral went from integrating $\theta_1\theta_2$ to integrating $- \theta_2\theta_1$. If the two are equal they must be zero.

Comment: Anyway, it is the same reason that the integral $\int_{-1}^1 x f(x) ~\mathrm{d}x = 0$ for any even function $f(x)$.